# using dynamic fields in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have an Item schema and collection and a List Schema and collection.

I currently create items separately from creating lists...but each item references a list objectId.

```
var ListSchema = new Schema({
    name    : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
  , user  : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true }
  , description : { type: String, trim: true }
});


var ItemSchema = new Schema({ 
    name    : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
  , description: { type: String, trim: true }
  , list  : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'List', index: true }
});
```

I want to know if it's possible to get a list and load the items for that list ontop of that instance:

So I could do:

`list.items` to get all the items in the view.

```
//routes/list.js
List.find({ user: req.params.userid }, function(err, lists){
   //i want to populate list.items here
   res.render('/lists', { lists: lists });
});

//views/list.ejs
<% lists.forEach(function(list){ %>
    List has <%= list.items.length %> items in it
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you would want to run a query for all items whose `list` field was equal to the list's id.  Is that correct?

In that case, something like

```
lists.forEach(function(list){
   list.items = []
   Item.find( { list:list._id }, function(err, items) {
       items.forEach(function(item) {
           list.items.add(item);
       });
   });
});
```

might be what you want.

**Edit**

Ah, I see.  How about creating a list of all of the _ids of the lists you find, then doing an $in query on the Item collection to get all the items whose `list` property is one of the lists you have found?  This would only be one call to MongoDB to get all of the items, and you could put the `res.render` call inside of its callback.

Note: there would have to be some extra logic in the callback to parse the returned items and sort them by list.

Here are the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) for $in.

Comment: This will work, I was wondering if there was a more of a mongo-ish way to do this. Or create a List.methods.items function that does this for me.

Comment: By mongo-ish, do you mean within the same query on the List collection?  Since you want to get data from two separate collections, you will need to execute two queries.

Comment: This won't work, because I need to call res.render() after populating list.items.  The Item.find() is in a loop, which is where I would have to do it..